# How to decrease result amount in django sitemap index

Tags: django, django-sitemaps

According to the django site, when using django sitemap index, once results are over 50,000 entries a new sitemap is paginated and created.  The problem is that 50,000 is crushing my system, even with caching.

How can I decrease the sitemap entries to something more manageable like maybe a few thousand.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a limit attribute:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.limit

This can be implemented by:

```
class CompaniesSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "monthly"
    priority = 0.9
    limit = 5000
```